# Play phone's audio through GNU/Linux server over bluetooth

Tags: linux, audio, debian, bluetooth

I'd like to let my phone play its music via my home-server's speakers.  This home-server is a headless OrangePi box running Debian (and with a bluetooth dongle in one of its USB ports).

I followed https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser for the first steps and things seem to be working OK for the pairing part: my USB dongle is recognized, I can power it up, make it discoverable, it shows up on my phone, and I was able to pair up with it.

But now my phone doesn't seem to consider than my server is able to play audio.  `bt-device -i <phone>` tells me: `... UUIDs: [..., AudioSource, ..., HeadsetAudioGateway, ...]` which I understand to mean that my phone can use those two profiles to send audio.  But `bt-adapter -i` does not list those (or anything similar), which I understand to mean that I somehow need to teach my server how to receive audio from bluetooth.  I installed `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` but just installing it didn't seem to make any difference and I'm not sure what I else I could do.

[ BTW, I mention pulseaudio because my search lead me to it being part of a potential solution, but a solution that doesn't use pulseaudio would be fine as well.  ]

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same with a debian-jessie laptop. The following solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -y bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill blueman

# https://tttwrites.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/resolved-bluetooth-loading-patch-failed-in-debian-wheezy/
if [ $(lsusb|grep Blue|grep Atheros|wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then sudo apt-get install -y firmware-atheros; fi

# To fix the errors:
#  Sap driver initialization failed.
#  sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
# https://askubuntu.com/a/802345/155829
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover # not sure we need this line
modprobe ath3k
modprobe btusb
modprobe bluetooth

# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Using_your_computer.27s_speakers_as_a_bluetooth_headset
echo '[General]
Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket' > /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf

sudo service bluetooth restart || sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
if [ $(ps awuxf|grep blueman-app|wc -l) -lt 2 ]; then blueman-applet; fi
```

It is worth learning to use bluetoothctl as I needed it to enter a PIN

When it is working:

```
lsmod |grep -i blue|awk '{print $1}'
```

shows me

```
bluetooth    
ecdh_generic 
rfkill       
crc16
```

and once paired with the phone

```
ls -la /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb|grep dev
```

has some symlink to -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/{YOUR DEVICE}
and

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/{remove_id,new_id}|wc -c
```

Should return return 0 (zero), where before it was a positive value when it did not work.